# UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' in Agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, computed-column, quoted-identifier

In brief, I added a computed column to a table and then Agent jobs began failing and reporting the error:

> UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 1934).

An [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243991/update-failed-because-the-following-set-options-have-incorrect-settings-quoted) suggests that stored procedures must be created with QUOTED_IDENTIFIER set ON. In my case, however, there are no stored procedures. One example Agent job has one step and that contains straight SQL to carry out two updates - each update is against the table I altered. None of that SQL contains a double-quote character (which is the subject of QUOTED_IDENTIFIER).

Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says:

> SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER must be ON when you are creating or changing
>   indexes on computed columns or indexed views.

... however I simply added the column (persisted). I have not created or altered any indexes.

1. Why am I getting this error in this scenario?
2. How do I resolve this? Do I need to re-create all the Agent jobs, switching QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON before I do? Or do I need to switch QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON before altering the table to add the computed column?

Possibly related, the following SQL shows which objects in the database had QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON at compile time (ie. which will be interpreted with that value when used). From this I see that triggers are also affected by this setting. Perhaps the Agent job update is invoking a trigger which is somehow related? I do note, however, that all objects are listed as uses_quoted_identifier = 1. In other words, if the resolution was to re-create objects while setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON prior to re-creating them, I don't see what difference it would make; all objects already seem to have been created that way.

```
SELECT uses_ansi_nulls, uses_quoted_identifier, name, *
 FROM sys.sql_modules -- WHERE object_id = object_id('SampleProcedure')
 left outer join sys.sysobjects on sql_modules.object_id = sysobjects.id
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why am I getting this error in this scenario?

The agent itself is switching `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` to `OFF`.

I have written about it [here](https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/when-the-sql-server-agent-overrides-default-behavior-quoted_identifier/) (*mind the unreadable font, not my choice*).

Here are the tests run on sql server 2012 to sql server 2017:

If I run this query in a ssms query window:

```
DECLARE @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';  
IF ( (256 & @@OPTIONS) = 256 ) SET @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER = 'ON';  
SELECT @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER AS QUOTED_IDENTIFIER;
```

The result shows as on:

```
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
ON
```

When I put the query to check the quoted identifier in a job and run it, this happens:

```
create table dbo.QUOTEDIDENTIFIER_CHECK(QUOTEDIDENTIFIER varchar(3));


DECLARE @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';  
IF ( (256 & @@OPTIONS) = 256 ) SET @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER = 'ON';  
SELECT @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER AS QUOTED_IDENTIFIER;  

insert into dbo.QUOTEDIDENTIFIER_CHECK(QUOTEDIDENTIFIER)
select @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER;
```

[image]
View the results:

```
select * from dbo.QUOTEDIDENTIFIER_CHECK;
```

Result:

```
QUOTEDIDENTIFIER
OFF
```

When tracing the agent, you can clearly see the statement that turns quoted identifier off.

[image]

> How do I resolve this? Do I need to re-create all the Agent jobs,
>   switching QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON before I do?

To resolve this you have to add explicit `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;` statements to the agent job steps.

Comment: Thanks Randi. I haven't managed to test this solution yet but when I do, if it succeeds, I'll be sure to come back here to accept your answer.

Comment: @youcantryreachingme great! Thanks for getting back to me & Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to add to the step:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

And then the creation of the computed column.

```
ALTER TABLE ...
```

This way the Agent jobs run smoothly

Comment: Adding `ANSI_NULLS, ` to the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;` statement fixed it for me